# How to put AND, NOT condition in DSL query

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

- Below query will give search the document with programmer or tester

`query = {'from': 0, 'size': 30,  'query': {'bool': {'must': {'query_string': {'query': '*programmer* OR *tester*'}}}}}`

How to get document contain `programmer and tester` not `manager`

Below query not working.

`query = {'from': 0, 'size': 30,  'query': {'bool': {'must': {'query_string': {'query': '*programmer* AND *tester* NOT *manager*'}}}}}`

Q2: Also many result are popping up for me, how to give show only the result min_score > 5 ?

Q3:
If i want to extract document with '*programmer* AND *tester* AND *manager*, if three strings(programmer, tester,manager) are present then only how to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `must_not` query. This is an example query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*programmer* OR *tester*"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*manager*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should also work without a `must_not` query:

```
(*programmer* OR *tester*) AND NOT *manager*
```

Comment: thanks @YD9, If i want to extract document which contain programmer and tester and manager. what  need to be done

Comment: I updated the answer to solve it without a must_not query. I think you should add an `AND` before the `NOT`

Comment: so many result are popping up for me, how to give show only the result min_score  > 5 ?

Comment: If i want to extract document which contain programmer and tester and manager. what need to be done , basically extract document with only programmer and tester and manager